# /usr/include/rdma/rdma_cma.h:91:2: error: unknown type name ‘__be16’ __be16 pkey;

Tags: rdma

when I was install SOft-iWARP on ubuntu16.04 to support the RDMA without the expensive hardware, I met with this. I have both linux-headers-4.8.0-39-generic and linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic on my computer. Is it the problem of linux-core ? how can I fix it?

Comment: `linux/types.h` which is indirectly included from `rdma_cma.h` (through `infiniband/verbs.h`) should have the definition of `__be16`. Can you perhaps add the command line you were trying to run?

Comment: oh, it's exactly what you said, wrong path causes this problem, thank you so much !